# Why do I get an extra garbage output?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int aka(int x, int y){
    cin >> x >> y;
    x+=2;
    y*=2;
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y << endl;
}
int main () {
    int x,y;
    cout << aka(x,y);
}
```

In this program, the output is to add `2` to the first integer, multiply `2` to the second integer, However when I enter `2` `4` as inputs, I get `4` `8`and `5007456` as output Why am I getting this trash number?

Comment: So... what's `aka()` missing?

Comment: Because you wrote `cout << aka(x, y);`?

Comment: @immibis What should I write instead?

Comment: `aka` isn't returning anything.

Comment: You should write aka(x,y); instead of cout << aka(x,y);

Comment: `aka` is declared to return a `int`, so you *must always* return a `int` - currently you don't. If you don't want to return anything from the function, declare it to return `void` instead.

Comment: Perhaps enable your warnings on your compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three times in this program where stuff is printed:

```
// prints 4
cout << x << endl;

// prints 8
cout << y << endl;

// prints 5007456 (or some other garbage number)
cout << aka(x,y);
```

`cout << aka(x, y);` prints the return value of `aka(x, y)`, but there is no return statement in `aka`, so a garbage value is returned. (You *should* get a compiler warning)

Comment: Can I use return x; return y; instead of cout << x << endl; cout << y << endl; 
But when I call it, it returns only one value.

Comment: @AnthonyMichael because that's how returning works. a function returns one value (or none if it's `void`) and returning ends the function.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ function returns only one value.
If you want to access those values in main, use address operator.

`void aka(int &x, int &y)`

you don't need any return value.